# Performance issue with big file reading/writing in C++

Tags: c++, linux, qt, sockets, io

I'm developing an application over Qt.

In this application the main thread is a web server. Another thread sometimes read data from big files (250mb) and write them in a output file (~2gb).

This thread performs high I/O operation on file, and CPU iowait is around 70%.

My problem is that when writing into the file, the web server is not responding quickly. What i understood is that the server's qt socket (on Linux) is represented by a system socket connected to the poll or select event system. So Qt send signal to my application only when poll emit event.

What i think is that too huge io operation with file writing may block the poll system, so my qt server doesn't receive socket event. When the thread has finished to write its data, everything become normal.

The file writing look like this:

```
while(dataToRead){
    // context has the list of files to read and current step
    dataToRead = extractData(context, &pBuffer, &sizeBuf);

    fwrite (pBuffer, 1, sizeBuf, pOutFile);

    free(pBuffer);
    pBuffer = NULL;

    // usleep(100000);
}
```

If i add a break with usleep function, this help to avoid the problem but not completely if i don't use a big enough sleep. But too big sleep destroy the performance, and i was the file generated as fast as possible.

What i'm doing wrong? Is it safe to read/write into a file as fast as possible? Is a sleep is mandatory in the above function? But how can we know the good timeslice?

I'm working on Mint LMDE, Linux 3.2.0 64 bits with Intel Core i5 2500 and standard HDD drive.

Edit:
A sample program that reproduce the problem is available here: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/secure/attachment/30436/TestQtBlocked.zip. Need qt's qmake to compile it. If you run it, it will create an empty 3GB file, the worker thread will be launched at startup and will create the file during few seconds. During this time, if you try to connect to http:// localhost:8081/ and you run many F5 to refresh the page, you will see that sometime it's not responding quickly.
If could be helpful if someone can reproduce my problem with my sample program, and let me know.

Comment: How big chunks of data are you writing ? i.e. what's the normal value of sizeBuf ?

Comment: @Mike: It's Qt, so it's C++. Why he'd use `cstdio` instead of `fstream` is beyond me.

Comment: @nos: Data is JPEG image so it can vary from 20Kb to 200kb, sizeBuf is not static and correspond to image size.

Comment: @Mike: In fact, Qt is for the high level part of my program, and it use module written with C or c++ code but not using qt.

Comment: @Mike: The 250Mb contains lots of picture, extractData function search in the file for desired picture and copy it in the buffer. Yes the file write is done in another thread. First, i was thinking it's a Qt problem, so I made a simple test program that reproduce the problem. You can find it here: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28539

Comment: This test program don't read image, just generate a big file. I tried to reduce chunk to 10kb or 1024 byte but it is the same.

Comment: You must check the return value of fwrite(), it might be smaller than sizeBuf if not all bytes could have been written. Then you'd lose data. I don't see how file writing could become a serious bottleneck if the data it writes comes over the network.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld No in fact, in my program i have a web server that allow me to create file operation tasks from a GUI, and the secondary thread must handle the tasks and performs IO operations. So writing the file do nothing over the network. it just while the tasks is processing, it block the socket event of my web server and the GUI is not easily accessible.

Comment: In the meantime, thank you all for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are starving the main thread's select calls, create a separate thread to do the file I/O. When the event comes from Qt, trigger some kind IPC that wakes up your worker thread to do the big file I/O and return from your event handler immediately.

(This assumes that writing to the file asynchronously makes sense to your program logic. Only you can figure out if that is true.)

Comment: That's not really what i have want. As I said in a comments, in my program i have a web server that allow me to create file operation tasks from a GUI, and the secondary thread must handle the tasks and performs IO operations. While the tasks is processing, it block the socket event of my web server and the GUI is not easily accessible. So actually, IO file are already done in a thread, but this is not related to Qt any event. This is just the web server request that is.

Comment: Is the file thread used by Qt or is it a completely separate thread? How are you signalling the file thread from the webserver thread?

Comment: Yes, the file thread is another thread than the main thread. When i create a task it goes in a queue, and the worker thread receive an event that a new task is pending. And it start to process the file writing. I also tried put the web server in another thread, but it doesn't solve the problem. I posted a sample program above that reproduce the problem if you want more source code.

Answer (score 0):

from the man page:
      size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb,
                     FILE *stream);

You want to write sizeBuf , 1 element.

You may want to tune buffering with setvbuf.

setvbuf(pOutfile, NULL, _IONBF, 0) - to disable buffering.

Complete example at:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frtref%2Fsetvbuf.htm

better switch to work with file descritors, not file streams.

Using file descriptors you can use sendfile and slice.
man sendfile
man slice

Comment: sendfile only works on sockets now but you can get the same benefit by using mmap

Comment: I tried to invert size and count and use it with or without the setvbuf function, but it change nothing.

Comment: Eric Beuque - The slow part in the test program is constant alloc/free of memory, is that the case in the real code? Also can you repeat the test with shmfs or tmpfs - to eliminate the disk. Also you can try to fiddle with the block device scheduler.

Comment: I tried with a constant buffer that is allocated only one time, but i got the same issue. Nevertheless, you're right, i haven't any trouble with tmpfs, but the file writing is too fast so i change the test to write multiple time the same. So it seems to be an HDD speed problem that block I/O event, but i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: IF you must use regular file one of the options is to separate the file generation into a process, not a thread , so you can change it's ionice (AFAIK you can not change thread ionice). Spawn it with a lower ionice and it would not block serving of requests.